# Sample Flex with Pojo on Server

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds, pojo

I just started a new project and my boss wants us to change IDE from NetBeans to Eclipse, RichFaces to Flex. I have never worked with Eclipse and Flex before.
Today I tried to make hello word with it on Eclipse but had no luck.
Can some one post or give me link to Flex->BlazeDS->Pojo on Eclipse for Beginner (Dummy) :D
Thanks

**Update:** Forgot to mention that I'm using glassfish but I don't think it will make any problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a pretty good tutorial: [Set up blazeds on tomcat with eclipse for FLEX](http://techmytongue.blogspot.com/2008/11/set-up-blazeds-on-tomcat-with-eclipse.html).  Heres the POJO they use:

```
package test;

public class tester {
public String getData() {
return "hi";
}
}
```

Comment: not very helpful, can't make it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't address BlazeDS or Pojo, but Adobe has an excellent [series of free training videos](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining/) for Flex and Flex Builder.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this book:[Beginning Java Flex](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430223855), it got me up an running in a couple of days and is a pretty good intro to flex, blazeds, spring and hibernate, and an easy read.  It walks you through some examples for each section.